# Python and Conda not recognized in Ubuntu for Windows, although in PATH

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Anaconda on my Windows machine, and made sure to add it to PATH.
Ubuntu for Windows will not recognize `conda` and `python` although they are in PATH

```
dean@DESKTOP-GJ4INGE:~$echo $PATH
...
/mnt/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3
/mnt/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/mingw-w64/bin
/mnt/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/usr/bin
/mnt/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/bin
/mnt/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts
...
```

I've wanted to make sure They actually exists in PATH, so I opened Anaconda prompt

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>where conda
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe

(base) C:\Windows\system32>where python
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Seems as if they are in the correct locations yet not recognized by Ubuntu.

Comment: Where does Ubuntu come into play in this question?

Comment: I'm using the Ubuntu terminal for Windows

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Ubuntu is looking for the entire file name so the command `conda.exe` and `python.exe` work.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a better and more useful idea to install python directly on WSL via `sudo apt install python3 python3-pip` and manually install the ubuntu package for conda.

If you want to preserve your current WSL configuration, the output from `which python`, `which python` and `which conda` and the complete `echo $PATH` would be needed to help you more. (All the commands in WSL)

From what you have submited I think your PATH is bad written because instead of newline the separator character between directories should be ':'.

Comment: Then you should add the directories you removed from the output of PATH, it would be useful to know if the executables of the removed directories have more priority than the directories you added to PATH.